# Selecting month and year for SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I currently have a code which selects certain sql queries based on certain information. It is currently as this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE id_task = '2' AND id_child = '$number' AND MONTH(datetime) = MONTH('2016-02-13 20:36:41')";
```

The problem is that while it does in fact select the correct month, I would also like to specify the year, however, I do not know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: AND YEAR(datetime) = YEAR('2016-02-13 20:36:41')?

Comment: You can use same thing like for month: `AND YEAR(datetime) = YEAR('some date...')` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution would be like this:

```
MONTH(datetime) = MONTH('2016-02-13 20:36:41')
and YEAR(datetime) = YEAR('2016-02-13 20:36:41')
```

but a better and more performant approach that can make use of an index is this:

```
WHERE
  datetime>=subdate(date('2016-02-13 20:36:41'), (day('2016-02-13 20:36:41')-1))
  and datetime<last_day('2016-02-13 20:36:41')+interval 1 day
```

this will calculate the first day of the given month:

```
subdate(date('2016-02-13 20:36:41'), (day('2016-02-13 20:36:41')-1))
```

and this will calculate the first day of the next month:

```
last_day('2016-02-13 20:36:41')+interval 1 day
```

so you can simply use `>=first_day_of_given_month` and `<first_day_of_next_month`